# I want to start using Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9 but how can I still run my Rails 2 apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I have some production Rails 2 apps. I want to start using Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9 for new apps I develop.

I'm using Passenger and Apache with REE (Ruby 1.8.7). I don't vendor anything -- I install gems on the system level and specify versions per app in `environment.rb`.

If understand it right, the problem is not so much the Rails and other gem versions (because each app can specify their own in `environment.rb`), but whether my Rails 2 apps and their gems will run under Ruby 1.9.

Do I have that right?

Based on Googling it appears that there may actually be a problem with some gems like Searchlogic and Ruby 1.9.

If so what would be the recommended solution?

---

I have looked into RVM and it looks fantastic for testing, experimentation, and development. But it doesn't look like it was designed help with a production setup.

As I understand it, when you install Passenger you compile it against one particular version of Ruby. That Ruby can be under RVM no problem, but Passenger can't use different Rubies for different apps.

Comment: I'm uncertain the nature of the apps you are deploying but couldn't you put them on Heroku? Their older stacks support 1.8.7.

Comment: For personal projects that might be an option, but not for these applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into RVM (Ruby Version Manager).  You can manage multiple ruby versions on the same box, and multiple gemsets for each.

http://beginrescueend.com/

Additionally, Bundler allows projects to maintain their own libraries of gems (and for me at least, obviates the need for using RVM gemsets)

http://gembundler.com/

Check the following link for Hongli Lai from Phusion explaining how to set up Passenger running on multiple versions of Ruby simultaneously by using Passenger standalone and reverse proxy.

http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/

Comment: Thanks, I have checked out RVM. Problem is, I don't thing that ca help me run different Ruby versions under one instance of Passenger. As I understand it, you compile Passenger against one specific Ruby version.

Comment: You can install passenger for multiple versions.  Check this out http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/.  Doesn't seem to be the most straightforward solution (reverse proxying to passenger on additional ruby versions), but it can be done.

Comment: The guy that created rvm also has bdsm http://bdsm.beginrescueend.com/ I am guessing using it you could run 2 passengers side by side, not sure if there is an extension for passenger yet?

Comment: Thanks again. I appreciate the help. Yes, you're right -- it looks like there is a way that may work in some circumstances. I'm sorry to say I'm reluctant to go down that path. I've been burned badly by delicate and specialized setups from peoples' blog posts. Since this is for a client and time is short I'm inclined to stay with solutions that are solidly validated and established, even if that means the only option is just to stick with Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 2.

Comment: Just for the record, that post is from the Phusion (the authors of Passenger) blog and seems to be their recommended solution, so it's probably fairly solid.  But yeah, if you have something working for you and not much time to experiment, it might be best to stick to what you know works :-)

Comment: @ethan..if you want Rails3 only, Rails 3 can be run in Ruby 1.8.7..I am using Rails 2 and Rails 3 app in same server, with Ruby 1.8.7..but yes, u wil miss the new features of Ruby 1.9